# How to set margin for Vertical Scrollbar from the right edge in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, margin

For Android Platform:

I need to put margin on right side of the vertical scrollbar in listview (it is customized). Please see the attached image. Default scrollbar sticks to the extream right side of the listview.
[image]

Need your hand. Thanks.

Comment: What platform/GUI framework is this for? Lots of them have vertical scrollbars and ListViews.

Comment: This is for Android Platform for 2.1 and above.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Refer to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle) on `android:scrollbarStyle` attribute of `View`. The style you probably want to use is `insideOverlay` (in conjunction with `android:paddingRight`).

Something like

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="50dip">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scrollable_table" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Why not the padding directly in the ListView without using the wrapper?

Comment: @Michael's answer is much better. Please review it and consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: Note: if you need the opposite (make scroll bar gravitate to right) and have `paddingRight` and `clipToPadding = false`, use `outsideOverlay `

Answer (score 47):

If you care about your design and want to apply the style globally use this.

---

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
```

**res/drawable/scrollbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="4dp"> <!-- Your Margin -->
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/red500" /> <!-- Your Color -->
            <corners android:radius="2dp" /> <!-- Your Radius -->
            <size android:width="4dp" /> <!-- Your Width -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

All the other answers were created by developers, not designers like myself.

**Result**

[image: Good ScrollBar]

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Tnx Michael!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give more than one upvote. This answer deserves 100.

Answer (score -2):

Try enabling fast scroll, it does the job most of the time:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chapter_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: This does not answering to the question.